# Return the list of tags that every selected (e.g. where selected is true) candidate shares

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given an array of candidates, who follow this type:

```
type Candidate = {
  name: string,
  tags: string[],
  selected: boolean,
};
```

How do I return the list of tags that every selected candidate shares? Tags are only included in the result if every single selected candidate has that tag. The order of tags in the output doesn't matter.

```
function sharedTags(candidates) {
  // code goes here
  return [];
}

module.exports = sharedTags;
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's break down the steps of what you're looking to accomplish.

First, you'll need to identify which candidates are selected. You can do this with the standard `Array.filter(predicateFn)`. Your predicate, will look something along the lines of `function(c) { return c.selected === true; }`.

It's worth saying that if you can structure your code such that the `candidates` parameter is always supplied with an array of selected candidates, that first step will be unnecessary. As with most things in software, it depends on the assumptions you're willing to make.

Next, you'll compute a collection representing the (ed: updated) intersection of tags between the collection of candidates. This involves writing a helper function that can take two candidates and determine whether they have any tags in common:

```
var sharedTags = function(c1, c2) { 
    return c1.tags.filter(function(t) { 
        return c2.tags.indexOf(t) >= 0;
    });
};
```

EX:

```
var c1 = { name: 'Jo', tags: ["red", "blue", "green"]};
var c2 = { name: 'Bill', tags: ["yellow", "blue", "purple"]};
var shared = sharedTags(c1, c2); // ["blue"]
```

Comment: absolutely right @Barmar! Thanks for the correction - I always mix up those two terms when describing them!

Answer (score -1):

- A **fast** approach is to have a `Map` of tags which has `key` as `tag name` and `value` as `tag frequency`.
- Loop through each candidate's tags and prepare a **unique** map of tags. The reason for **distinct** tags is because it may so happen that same tags gets repeated multiple times for a single candidate. So, this could break our core deciding check of whether a tag appears for all candidates.
- Have a global `map` variable which keeps track of tags and their frequencies.
- Now, in the end, iterate over all tags in `map` and check if it's frequency happens to be 
  equal to `candidates.length`. If yes, it occurred in every candidate, else it didn't.
- This way, you visit each candidate's tags only once.
- Below is an implementation to demonstrate the same.

**CODE:**

```
function sharedTags(candidates) {
    var results = [];
    var map = {};
    // collect each tag's frequency in a map
    for(let i=0;i<candidates.length;++i){
        let each_candidate = candidates[i];
        if(each_candidate['selected'] === true){
            // collect all unique tags for this candidate in iteration
            let unique_tags = {};

            for(let j=0;j<each_candidate['tags'].length;++j){
                let tag = each_candidate['tags'][j];
                unique_tags[tag] = unique_tags[tag] === undefined ? 1 : unique_tags[tag];
            }

            // merge it's presence with the global "map" variable
            let this_candidate_tags = Object.keys(unique_tags);
            for(let k=0;k<this_candidate_tags.length;++k){
                if(map[this_candidate_tags[k]] === undefined){
                    map[this_candidate_tags[k]] = 1;
                }else{
                    map[this_candidate_tags[k]] += 1;
                }
            }
        }        
    }

    // now check for frequency of each tag. If it equals candidates length, that means it appeared in every candidate.
    var tags = Object.keys(map);
    for(let each_tag in tags){
        if(map[tags[each_tag]] === candidates.length){
            results.push(tags[each_tag]);
        }
    }

    return results;
  }
```

Comment: This is pushing the tags to an array even if the boolean "selected" is false. how would you only look at tags where selected is true?

Comment: @JohnMatrix you can add a `if` conditional check before declaration of `unique_tags` .

Comment: i did not downvote. you have been very helpful. i am still having trouble with the placement of the conditional.

Comment: @JohnMatrix Edited my code and added the conditional check. Hope it helps you now. I was sure you didn't down vote and I didn't point to you anyway. Cheers :)